# Native HTML5 Drag and Drop: Make draggable object NOT droppable

Tags: javascript, html

I have a basic drag and drop using native HTML5 drag and drop. I am wondering how to make the draggable divs not droppable, meaning currently, other draggable divs can be dropped into them.

Here is the location of that page: http://www.ritechhub.umn.edu/interactions/see/drag/sourcesofhealthinfo.html

Here is my code:

```
<!doctype HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Sources of Health Information</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript">

    function allowDrop(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
    }

    function drag(ev) {
        ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
    }

    function drop(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
        ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));

        var temp1 = ev.target.id; //this is the variable that displays the ID of the "dropped" area
        //data is the ID of the item "being dropped" or the "draggable"

        if (temp1 == "div1") {

            if (data == "c" || data == "f" || data == "i" || data == "j" || data == "l" || data == "n" || data == "s" || data == "u" || data == "w") {
                document.getElementById(data).style.color = "#007A00";
                document.getElementById(data).style.fontWeight = "900";
                document.getElementById(data).style.textDecoration = "none";
            } else {
                document.getElementById(data).style.color = "red";
                document.getElementById(data).style.textDecoration = "line-through";
            }
        }
        if (temp1 == "div2") {
            if (data == "b" || data == "g" || data == "o" || data == "q" || data == "r") {
                document.getElementById(data).style.color = "#007A00";
                document.getElementById(data).style.fontWeight = "900";
                document.getElementById(data).style.textDecoration = "none";
            } else {
                document.getElementById(data).style.color = "red";
                document.getElementById(data).style.textDecoration = "line-through";
            }
        }
        if (temp1 == "div3") {
            if (data == "a" || data == "d" || data == "e" || data == "h" || data == "k" || data == "m" || data == "p" || data == "t" || data == "v" ) {
                document.getElementById(data).style.color = "#007A00";
                document.getElementById(data).style.fontWeight = "900";
                document.getElementById(data).style.textDecoration = "none";
            } else {
                document.getElementById(data).style.color = "red";
                document.getElementById(data).style.textDecoration = "line-through";
            }
        }

    }


</script>
<noscript><noscript>
<p>This page requires javascript. Please enable javascript and reload. If you are using a screen reader, <a href="" target="_blank" alt="Download the contents of this page (PDF)" title="Download the contents of this page (PDF)" >please download this PDF file</a> to access the content on this page. We apologize for any inconvenience. </p>
</noscript>
</noscript>
</head>
<body>
<div id="main">
    <div id="instructions">
        <h1>Sources of Health Information<a href="#accessible" alt="For learners using a screen reader" title="For learners using a screen reader">&#42;</a></h1>
        <p>Match the characteristics and examples with the most appropriate type of source of information.<br>Correctly placed items will turn green and appear <strong>bold</strong>. Incorrect items will appear red and be <span style="text-decoration:line-through"">crossed out.</span></p>

    </div>
    <div id="words">
        <div id="a" class="singleword" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" aria-grabbed="true">Condensed into brief, easy-to-read format for general public (tertiary)</div>
        <div id="b" class="singleword" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" aria-grabbed="true">Textbooks (secondary)</div>
        <div id="c" class="singleword" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" aria-grabbed="true">Peer-reviewed before publication (primary)</div>
        <div id="d" class="singleword" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" aria-grabbed="true">The least reliable source of information (tertiary)</div>
        <div id="e" class="singleword" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" aria-grabbed="true">Magazines (tertiary)</div>
        <div id="f" class="singleword" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" aria-grabbed="true">Provides a discussion and conclusion from research findings (primary)</div>
        <div id="g" class="singleword" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" aria-grabbed="true">Summarizes information from primary literature (secondary)</div>
        <div id="h" class="singleword" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" aria-grabbed="true">YouTube (tertiary)</div>
        <div id="i" class="singleword" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" aria-grabbed="true">Original research (primary)</div>
        <div id="j" class="singleword" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" aria-grabbed="true">The most reliable source of information (primary)</div>
        <div id="k" class="singleword" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" aria-grabbed="true">News sources (tertiary)</div>
        <div id="l" class="singleword" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" aria-grabbed="true">First-hand research (primary)</div>
        <div id="m" class="singleword" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" aria-grabbed="true">Allows for the most potential for error or misinterpretation (tertiary)</div>
        <div id="n" class="singleword" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" aria-grabbed="true">Tabulated sets of data (primary)</div>
        <div id="o" class="singleword" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" aria-grabbed="true">An interpretation of existing research is provided (secondary)</div>
        <div id="p" class="singleword" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" aria-grabbed="true">Often, only general conclusions of research are discussed (tertiary)</div>
        <div id="q" class="singleword" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" aria-grabbed="true">Reorganizes information from primary literature (secondary)</div>
        <div id="r" class="singleword" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" aria-grabbed="true">Review articles (secondary)</div>
        <div id="s" class="singleword" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" aria-grabbed="true">Conference papers (primary)</div>
        <div id="t" class="singleword" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" aria-grabbed="true">The most commonly encountered source of information for most people (tertiary)</div>
        <div id="u" class="singleword" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" aria-grabbed="true">Technical reports (primary)</div>
        <div id="v" class="singleword" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" aria-grabbed="true">Wikipedia (tertiary)</div>
        <div id="w" class="singleword" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" aria-grabbed="true">Contains a methods section (primary)</div>
    </div>
    <div class="threes">
        <h2>PRIMARY</h2>
        <div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" aria-dropeffect="move"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="threes">
        <h2>SECONDARY</h2>
        <div id="div2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" aria-dropeffect="move"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="threes">
        <h2>TERTIARY</h2>
        <div id="div3" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" aria-dropeffect="move"></div>
    </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>

    <div id="accessible">&#42;If you are using a screen reader, <a href="" target="_blank" alt="Download the contents of this page (PDF)" title="Download the contents of this page (PDF)" >please download this PDF file</a> to access the content on this page. We apologize for any inconvenience. </div>

</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div id="mobile">
        Greetings! If you're seeing this message, you are accessing this page on a mobile phone or your screen is too small. Please use a laptop or desktop or increase the size of your screen.
    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

sadf

Comment: Just as an aside, your 'mobile detection' is _probably_ unnecessary and also kind of broken.

Comment: Hi dtanders, I believe you are referring to the div #mobile. In my css, I hide this div if the screen width is a certain amount. And if the screen width is small enough, then I make it visible. I do this since the drag/drop doesn't work for mobile phones or ipads.

Comment: Right, that's not a good way to detect mobile devices.  I found it accidentally when I opened the developer console which made the window width too narrow, which is what I mean when I say "kind of broken".  If you really want to change any part of the display for mobile devices, use a CSS media query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't append to `event.target`, `event.target` will be the element that you dropped the element on and will not always be the element you attached the event on. Since you are using inline js pass `this`, which will reference the div1,div2, etc element, to your event callback

```
<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event,this)"></div>
```

Then have your drop callback like so

```
function drop(ev,ele) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    ele.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));

    var temp1 = ele.id;
    //...
}
```